# Firebase function separate threads?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that when called should grab all the document ids in a collection, then for each id run another function. I dont want the initial function to wait for responses of the looped function (i.e. fire and forget)

Psuedo code:

```
UpdateAllItems(){
    return this.getDocumentIds().then(ids => {
        ids.forEach(id => {
            this.updateItem(id) //returns a Promise
        })
    }
}
```

If I track the execution steps inside updateItem I see a log for each iteration all at once. So lets say there are 10 ids in the array, and the first step of updateItem is to fetch the document information, I see 10 logs of "Fetching document", then 10 seconds later I see 10 "Fetching step 2 information" logs.

If I was to run the same id 10 times in the above psuedo, it would take 60 seconds. If I ran that same updateItem call in Postman, I can manually call 10 in less than 10 seconds.

**Why does this loop seem to compound the time it takes?**

**Note** inside updateItem it makes 3 calls for other documents, aggregates that data, then does a .set(data, {merge, true})

Comment: In Cloud Functions, you can't really "fire and forget".  You are obliged to either send a response (for http type functions) or return a promise (for other types) that resolves **only after all the async work is complete**.  That means you must pay attention to every promise returned by every function, and use those to determine the right time to send the response or return the final promise.

Comment: @DougStevenson I return a HTTP response once getDocumentIds() has finished running, i just dont want to wait for the inner actions to finish as they may take a long time (few minutes)

Comment: In that case, they might never finish.  Cloud Functions will clamp down on ongoing work after the response is sent.  If you have ongoing work to execute after the response, you'll need to arrange for that to happen asynchronously by (for example) sending a message to a pubsub function which finishes the work.

Answer (score 0):

To separate thread I would recommend using [Background Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions#lifecycle_of_a_background_function).

Background function can be invoked by Google Cloud events originating from Pub/Sub or even Firestore or Firebase realtime database directly (currently in Beta). Here is the full [list to events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions#key_capabilities) that your function can respond to.

When your Promise resolves without errors, you can just send pub/sub message to another function with the result of the data aggregation. [Here you can find documentation for Pub/Sub triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events)

However, now you can also set the [event handlers for the Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) . So your background function can respond directly to events like onWrite() (triggered when data is created, updated, or deleted) or onCreate(), onUpdate().